# Arrays from Twitter json

Tags: php, arrays, twitter

I am trying to convert json feed from Twitter API 1.1 to arrays. What I am trying is

```
    foreach($user))
        Main_Array{
          Name:
          Id:
          Array{
                Array {
                       Tweet:
                       created at:
                       }
                Array {
                       Tweet:
                       created at:
                       }
          }
        }
    }

var_dump(Main_Array()); //unable to get the main array here. Only the last element of array is pulled
```

Here is what I tried:

```
$tweets = $connection->get("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=".$user."&count=".$notweets);

$status = array();

foreach($tweets as $key) {  
    $status['text'] = $key ->text;
    $status['stamp'] = $key -> created_at;
}

$tweetfeed = array (
        'name' => $name,
        'id' => $tweetname,
        'status' => $status         
);
```

I am only getting the last value for status array.

Also, I want to know if the structure I am using is good or please suggest if this can be better.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You overwrite the previous `$status` entries every time in your foreach loop. You've to create a new sub-array for each tweet.

Here is a way to do it :

```
$i = 0;
foreach($tweets as $key) {  
    $status[$i]['text'] = $key ->text;
    $status[$i]['stamp'] = $key -> created_at;
    ++$i;
}
```

Comment: Hi Malet. Now I got another problem. (I am not very familiar with foreach loop). I just edited my question. Unable to get the main parent array. Can you please suggest me for this. Thanks

Comment: @pmvsdt If you have another problem, you have to ask a new question. You should not edit your question to ask a new one. That is not how Stack Overflow works. But if the content of your new question is bound to this question, you can add a link to this question in the new one.

Comment: I thought it is related to this but anyway I will post a new question. Thanks